# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable, slider-crank mechanism

Tags: python, numpy

Now i have been working on this program to simulate the motion of the slider-crank mechanism in python.
I ran into a dead-end when I got this error. It's this method that's throwing up an error for no reason.

```
def returnSliderAcceleration(a,b,theta_1,omega_1,alpha_1): 
    rad_temporary = theta_1 * np.pi / 180
    rad_temporary_2 = returnConnectorAngle(a,b,theta_1)
    omega_2 = returnConnectorVelocity(a,b,theta_1,omega_1)
    alpha_2 = returnConnectorAcceleration(a,b,theta_1,omega_1,alpha_1)
    part_1 = a((alpha_1 * np.sin(rad_temporary)) + ((omega_1**2)*np.cos(rad_temporary)))
    part_2 = b((alpha_2 * np.sin(rad_temporary_2)) + ((omega_2**2)*np.cos(rad_temporary_2)))
    slider_acceleration = -1*(part_1 + part_2)
    return slider_acceleration
```

The other methods it makes use of are:

```
def returnConnectorAngle(a,b,theta_1):  #Returns the angle(in degrees) made by the connector corresponding to the crank angle, CCW taken as positive
    rad_temporary = theta_1 * np.pi / 180
    x = (a / b) * np.sin(rad_temporary)
    connector_angle = np.arcsin(x)
    return (connector_angle* np.pi / 180)

def returnConnectorVelocity(a,b,theta_1,omega_1):   #Returns the angular velocity of the connector, CCW taken as positive
    rad_temporary = theta_1 * np.pi / 180
    rad_temporary_2 = returnConnectorAngle(a,b,theta_1)
    Nr = a * omega_1 * np.cos(rad_temporary)
    Dr = b * np.cos(rad_temporary_2)
    connector_velocity = Nr / Dr
    return connector_velocity   

def returnConnectorAcceleration(a,b,theta_1,omega_1,alpha_1): #Returns the angular acceleration of the connector arm, CCW taken as positive
    rad_temporary = theta_1 * np.pi / 180
    rad_temporary_2 = returnConnectorAngle(a,b,theta_1)
    omega_2 = returnConnectorVelocity(a,b,theta_1,omega_1)
    Nr_1 = a * ((alpha_1 * np.cos(rad_temporary)) - ((omega_1**2)*np.sin(rad_temporary)))
    Dr_1 = b * np.cos(rad_temporary_2)
    part_2 = (omega_2**2) * np.tan(rad_temporary_2)
    return (Nr_1/Dr_1) + part_2
```

The Error:

```
slider_acceleration = -1*(a((alpha_1 * np.sin(rad_temporary)) + ((omega_1**2)*np.cos(rad_temporary)))+ b((alpha_2 * np.sin(rad_temporary_2)) + ((omega_2**2)*np.cos(rad_temporary_2))))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please format your code, it was a real pain doing so...

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new to this place and I was just editing when you did it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before we even look at your code let's take a closer look at the error Python is giving you:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

In this case, your error is a `TypeError`. That means that some Python type was used incorrectly. The more detailed description tells us two additional facts:

1. The type used incorrectly was an `int`
2. The problem was that we tried to *call* the `int`, but we can't do that- we can call `functions` and `methods`, but not `ints`

Here's a simple way to produce exactly the same problem:

```
$ python
>>> x = 3
>>> y = x(10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

We got this error because we tried to use `x` as a function with the parameter 10, but x is just an `int`. Now that we understand what this error means, let's take a look at your code. Here's the problematic line, split up over a few lines:

```
slider_acceleration = -1 * (
    a(
        (alpha_1 * np.sin(rad_temporary)) + \
            ((omega_1**2)*np.cos(rad_temporary))
    ) + b(
        (alpha_2 * np.sin(rad_temporary_2)) + \
            ((omega_2**2)*np.cos(rad_temporary_2))
    )
)
```

It looks like you're using `a` and `b` as functions, but are they? Taking a quick look at how they were used in other functions, I'd suspect not. Perhaps you meant to multiply them like this:

```
slider_acceleration = -1 * (
    a * (
        (alpha_1 * np.sin(rad_temporary)) + \
            ((omega_1**2)*np.cos(rad_temporary))
    ) + b * (
        (alpha_2 * np.sin(rad_temporary_2)) + \
            ((omega_2**2)*np.cos(rad_temporary_2))
    )
)
```

Comment: Ah that explains all of it. I just messed up the basic syntax. I solved the problem on paper and then while converting to code, I simply typed what was there on paper. Thanks a ton!